# Finding big O time complexity function using only run time data

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, big-o

In a project I have for my algorithm class we have to run 5 different sorting methods of unknown types and gather running time data for each of them using the doubling method for the problem size. We then have to use the ratio of the running times to calculate what the time complexity functions. The sorting methods used are selection sort, insertion sort, merge sort, and quicksort (randomized and non-randomized). We have to use empirical analysis to determine which type of sorting method is used in the five unknown methods in the program. My question is how does one go from the ratio to the function. I know that N = 2^k so we can use log(base2)ratio = k but I am not sure how that correlates with the time complexity of say mergesort which is O(N * log N).

Comment: Hi Ryan, maybe some of the work I did for my R package on the application of empirical complexity can help you: see here: https://github.com/agenis/GuessCompx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Big-O notation more or less describes a function, where the input `N` is the size of the collection, and the output is how much time will be taken.  I would suggest benchmarking your algorithms by running a variety of sample input sizes, and then collecting the running times.  For example, for selection sort you might collect this data:

```
N          | running time (ms)
1000       | 0.1
10000      | 10
100000     | 1000
1000000    | 100000
```

If you plot this, using a tool like R or Matlab, or maybe Excel if you are feeling lazy, you will see that the running time varies with the *square* of the sample size `N`.  That is, multiplying the sample size by 10 results in a 100-fold increase in running time.  This is `O(N^2)` behavior.

For the other algorithms, you may collect similar benchmark data, and also create plots.

Note that you have to keep in mind things like startup time which Java can take to begin running your actual code.  The way to deal with this is to take many data points.  Overall, linear, logarithmic, etc. behavior should still be discernible.

Comment: It might be worth noting that, in theory, you can have an algorithm which takes quadratic time below some really high threshold for N but linear time above it (which would thus be O(N), not O(N^2)), or any other combinations of behaviours. In practice this is really rare though.

Answer (score 0):

On a log-log graph (log of size vs log of running time) you will find that `O(n^k)` is a line of slope k.  That will let you tell `O(n)` from `O(n^2)` very easily.

To tell `O(n)` from `O(n log(n))` just graph `f(n)/n` vs `log(n)`.  A function that is `O(n)` will look like a horizontal line, and a function that is `O(n log(n))` will look like a line with slope 1.

Don't forget to throw both ordered and unordered data at your methods.

Answer (score 0):

you can just look at the growth by time;

- If linear (O(n)), doubling the input space just doubles the time, t -> 2t
- If quasi-linear(O(nlogn)), doubling the space just increase by 2n(log2n), t->2t(log2t)
- If quadratic (O(n^2)), doubling the input space just quadratically,t -> 4t^2

Note that the timings are theoretical. expect the values around some threshold.